# ros::Time between samples

Tags: ros, sensor, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to calculate time difference between data in consecutive sensor messages through the subscriber callbacks.
For example:
I subscribe to sensor_msgs::Imu for the imu data. I get 5 samples per 100ms. So each sample should have a time difference of 20ms with respect to the previous one.

So if the first one arrived at: 20.092s from the start of simulation, I expected the second one to show me a time stamp of 20.112s.
I am collecting the time information by using: 'ros::Time::Now()'.

However, the time stamp for all the five samples shows me : 20.092s. The rate at which my publish loop is running is 10Hz i.e. 100ms.

What should I be doing to improve the granularity of the time in the subscribed data?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
    ......//some code here

    sub_odom = nh.subscribe("odom", 100, &velCallback);

    ros::Publisher pub=nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel", 100);
    ...//some other code here
    ros::Rate rate(10);

    while(ros::ok()) 
    {      
        ros::spinOnce();
    
       //do some work

       //publish velocity message.
       publish.pub(msg) 

       rate.sleep();
   }
   ros::spin();
   return 0;
}

void velCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)
{ 
    if(!odomfile.is_open())
    {
        odomfile.open(name.c_str());
    }
             
    //do somework.
  
    odomfile << ros::Time::now().toSec() << ","      <-- Collecting timestamp
             << msg->pose.pose.position.x << "," 
             << msg->pose.pose.position.y << ","
             << msg->pose.pose.position.z
             << std::endl;
}
```

For example, some data from the imu is like this:

```
20.092, 0.517179, 0.00451321, 9.80055
20.092, -0.0139723, 0.00388159, 9.80482
20.092, -0.0058133, 0.00101918, 9.80735
20.092, 0.0031343, -0.00360347, 9.80619
20.092, 0.00066209, -0.00248975, 9.80001
20.192, 0.485803, 0.00368372, 9.80928
```

Please advise.
Regards,
rsmitha.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264116/ros::time-between-samples/) by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-06-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-06-19**:
You should put some of your code that is doing the timestamping in the question.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-06-19**:
Also do you mean 20.092 **ms**?   If it always that exact amount you could play with changing the rate that the publisher publishes- make the first two messages 20ms apart, then 30 ms before the third one- if it still shows 20.092s/ms then you have another issue.

**Comment by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on 2017-06-20**:
Hi @lucasw, thanks for responding. I have put some code to show the timestamping. 20.092 is just the simulation time I see in that set of data. It changes with each run.

**Comment by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on 2017-06-20**:
@lucasw, you are probably right in that, if I change the publishing rate to 50Hz, I might get the required timestamp, but the publishing and subscribing rates are to be different and ros::time should be able to show the difference, is what I thought.

**Comment by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on 2017-06-20**:
The time stamp shows a change after 100ms which is the publishing rate.My question, is why should the subscribing timestamp be affected by the publishing rate?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-06-21**:
I stripped out the irrelevant code to make it more readable.

**Comment by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on 2017-06-21**:
Thanks, @lucasw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're calling `ros::spinOnce()` at 10Hz, which means that it can only call the callbacks once every 100ms; in between it queues up messages until you call `ros::spinOnce()` again. If you need to respond to events with lower latency, you should call `ros::spinOnce()` more often or use `ros::spin()` and do your publishing with a timer or a separate thread.

It's also worth noting that there is a publish timestamp in the `nav_msgs/Odometry` header (in your case, `msg->header.stamp` ), which is the time that the data was captured or published, and that will be more accurate than using the time that your node received the message (ie `ros::Time::now()` ). Since there can be some transport delay between nodes, it's generally advisable to use the header timestamp whenever possible.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on 2017-06-20**:
Thanks @ahendrix. I was thinking of using the header.stamp value to see what I get. It makes more sense, as you have mentioned to use that value. Also, I need to look into publishing using a separate thread.